# Android draw9patch throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

I upgraded to Android SDK Tools r8 today and I can't seem to run the draw9patch tool.  I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/swingworker/SwingWorker
at com.android.draw9patch.Application$1.run(Application.java:48)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:633)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.swingworker.SwingWorker
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 9 more
```

I'm running snow leopard and have jre (or jdk?) 1.6.

Any ideas how to get this working?  Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting. Same for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Same for me here (Ubuntu 10.04, Official JDK 6). I think this is worth to be reported in the Android issues on http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: Reported. [Link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12979&can=6&q=draw9patch&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I have found a solution(Ubuntu 10.10, java-6-sun). Copy swing-worker.jar into /path_to_android_sdk/tools/lib. You can find swing-worker-1.1.jar in the same directory in SDK r7 or download it from [here](http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/prebuilt/common/swing-worker/swing-worker-1.1.jar).

Comment: Works on OSX (Snow Leopard) as well!  Thanks!

Comment: I just had the same experience with Windows XP. Definitely a bug. Had to download swing-worker-1.1.jar from the link as it nowhere to be found in Windows distro (and I have all platforms since 1.5)

Comment: This fixed my problem on Server 2008 64 bit as well.  However, I had to ensure I copied the file into android-sdk-windows\tools\lib directory as an administrator.  Saving the file directly from a download did not work due to the Windows folder mirroring functionality.

Comment: Fixed for me on win7/64. Thanks!!