# Issue with draw9patch

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android draw9patch throws NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370899/android-draw9patch-throws-noclassdeffounderror)

draw9path is a tool to edit 9-patch file. It worked well.
However, after the recent SDK update, I can not run draw9patch again, the error message is:
Any help would be really appreciated.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/swingworker/SwingWorker
 at com.android.draw9patch.Application$1.run(Application.java:48)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.swingworker.SwingWorker
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 ... 9 more

Comment: it looks like more problem with your JDK installation, what version of JDK do you have?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370899/android-draw9patch-throws-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: refer to answer http://codetrips.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-draw-9-patch-seems-broken-too.html. It works.

Answer (score -1):

The error log you posted show you are trying to use a SwingWorker... that's Swing stuff for Java on desktop, not part of Android. You should look into AsyncTask for a similar thing on Android.

Comment: draw9path is part of android SDK, its purpose is to edit 9-patch file. I didn't use SwingWorker or AsyncTask on Android. Thanx

Comment: I see, this is part of the SDK tools... do you have the java SDK installed properly on your host machine ? Maybe you need to install the JDIC separately... https://jdic.dev.java.net/index.html